# After executing setcap, why I still can't use tar and got an error "operation not permitted"?

Tags: linux, security, docker, capabilities

#### Question

I'm doing my internship, working on container security and recently I need to build a container which has security problem to do some tests. Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM dockerfiles/centos-lamp
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN wget https://github.com/RandomStorm/DVWA/archive/v1.0.8.tar.gz -O- | tar xvz --strip-components=1
RUN service mysqld start && mysqladmin -uroot password p@ssw0rd && service mysqld stop
EXPOSE 80
USER root
COPY ./Centos-vault-6.10.repo /home
COPY ./here_u_r.txt /root
WORKDIR /home
RUN rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/*
RUN cp -r ./Centos-vault-6.10.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
RUN yum clean all
RUN yum makecache
RUN cp /bin/tar .
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN rpm --rebuilddb && yum install -y sudo && yum install -y gcc
RUN usermod -aG wheel apache && \
        chmod u+s $(which find) && \
        chmod 700 $(which getcap) && \
        setcap 'cap_dac_read_search=ep' /home/tar
CMD ["supervisord", "-n"]
```

You can see, in the penultimate line, I want to give the tar executable in the /home directory the capability in order to read files. But I got an error when I used the tar file to zip something. Can someone give me a hand?

PS: I don't understand why when I check the capability of this file, I get **cap_dac_read_search+ep**, either. I didn't use setcap 'cap_dac_read_search+ep' /home/tar, but setcap **'cap_dac_read_search=ep'** /home/tar.

#### Actions in my shell + returned results

```
bash-4.1$ ls -la /home/tar
ls -la /home/tar
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 390616 Aug 24 22:56 /home/tar

bash-4.1$ find 1 -exec getcap /home/tar \;
find 1 -exec getcap /home/tar \;
/home/tar = cap_dac_read_search+ep

bash-4.1$ pwd
pwd
/home
bash-4.1$ ./tar -cvf /tmp/my.tar /tmp/1 /tmp/pip-build-root
./tar -cvf /tmp/my.tar /tmp/1 /tmp/pip-build-root
bash: ./tar: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you see:

```bash
bash-4.1$ ./tar -cvf /tmp/my.tar /tmp/1 /tmp/pip-build-root
./tar -cvf /tmp/my.tar /tmp/1 /tmp/pip-build-root
bash: ./tar: Operation not permitted
```

is that the Bounding set has denied the `cap_dac_read_search` capability from your shell.

In a normal environment, if you try the following, you will get:

```bash
bash$ grep CapBnd /proc/self/status
CapBnd: 000001ffffffffff
bash$ capsh --decode=000001ffffffffff
0x000001ffffffffff=cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_module,cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_mac_override,cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend,cap_audit_read,cap_perfmon,cap_bpf,cap_checkpoint_restore
```

If you try the same sequence under your container, you will likely obtain a hex value with a lot more zeros in it and the `--decode` of it will not include `cap_dac_read_search`.

The reason for the error you see is that `bash`'s attempt to invoke `tar` is denied by the kernel because the Permitted capabilities you are *requiring* to be made Effective at execution time (`cap_dac_read_search=ep`), cannot be made effective. Rather than allow the binary to stumble along with less than its required Effective capabilities raised, the kernel denies permission to *exec* the binary. This is a protection against a class of attack first performed against Sendmail more than 20 years ago. You can read more about the details of that [here](https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/thesendmailcapabilitiesissue).

There are a number of quirks with respect to how capabilities behave. Some are listed [here](https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/why-didnt-that-work#h.c4ebft5m2xok).